# Ajax ResponseText without reloading

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following form succeeds in sending data to MySQL db. but it fails to display the responseText inside the div `<div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>`.How can I get the response back?

```
<form id="form-id" class="ajaxform" action="register.jsp">
<label>First Name </label>
<input type="text" name="userName" />
<label>Password </label>
<input type="password" name="password" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<br>
<br>

<strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
<div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>
```

js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ajaxform").bind("submit",function(e){

e.preventDefault();

var ajaxurl = $(this).attr("action");

var data = $(this).serialize();

$.post(ajaxurl,data,function(responseText) {
          $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
},'json');
});
```

Comment: Are you sure responseText is what you are expecting back from the call?

Comment: I've a jsp code which I want to display. `String greetings = "Hello " + username + "Your Password is:" + password;

  response.setContentType("text/plain");
  response.getWriter().write(greetings);`

Comment: Good, but if you do alert(responseText); instead of the whole .text line, do you see that string there? If you don't, you know that the jsp file is not behaving correctly

Comment: I tried `alert(responseText)` , it didnt worked.

Comment: What do you mean with it didn't work? If the alert window did not show up at all it's likely there is an error in the $.post call. If it popped up completely empty, you probably have an issue with register.jsp

Comment: Try changing this `$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);` to this `$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').html(responseText);`

Comment: Thank You !!! I've got an alert msg. I removed the ` 'json' ` from the post method. and also changed `$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').html(responseText);` . A great thanks @Swati

Comment: @Claudio ThankYou, I posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem, here are the changes that I have made, I have provided 2 separate ways :

**register.html**

**Changes:**
Added one input field with type button, and a function call `onclick="saveUserInfo()"`

```
<body>
<form id="form-id" class="ajaxform" action="register.jsp">

    <label>First Name </label>

    <input id="userName" type="text" name="userName" />

    <input id="password" type="text" name="password" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    <input type="button" id="button" value="SEND via AJAX" onclick="saveUserInfo()">


</form>

<br>
<br>

<strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
<div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**script.js**

When the user clicks the `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
try {
$(".ajaxform").bind("submit",function(e){

e.preventDefault();

var ajaxurl = $(this).attr("action");

var data = $(this).serialize();

$.post(ajaxurl,data,function(responseText) {
$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').html(responseText)
});
});
} catch(e) {
alert("You messed something up!");
}
});
```

also, I tried this way,

**script.js**

And when the user clicks, 
`<input type="button" id="button" value="SEND via AJAX" onclick="saveUserInfo()">`

```
function saveUserInfo(){
var username = document.getElementById("userName").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

var vars = "userName="+username+"&password="+password;

$.ajax({
url: 'register.jsp',
type: 'POST',
data: vars,
})
.done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
}
```

Also here is the **register.jsp** page for more reference.

```
<body>

<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>


<%

String username = request.getParameter("userName");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
    if(username == null || "".equals(username)){
            username = "Guest";
        }

    String greetings = "Hello, " + username +"." +" Your Password is : "  +password + 
    ".";

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(greetings);


Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_info4","root","root");

Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;

int i=st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `new table`(username, password) VALUE 
('"+username+"','"+password+"')");
 %>

</body>
```